# Assimp linker error - undefined references

Tags: c++, build, linker, cmake, assimp

I have been trying to install `Assimp 3.0` recently to load models from `Blender` to use in `OpenGL`.

My project is setup in `Sublime Text 3`, so I have created `CMake` files to generate the required `make` files for me to build my project.

All of the other libraries I am using, for example `SFML`, are being included and linked fine, but for some reason `Assimp` isn't working.

On build I get the following linker errors:

```
undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::Importer()
undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::~Importer()
undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::~Importer()
```

Since this is a linker error I am under the assumption that my problem lies in my `CMake` files.

I created a `FindASSIMP.cmake` file to set some variables for me with the correct include directory and the path of the `.lib` files that need to be linked, and I can see that it is working fine because I can print the resulting variables and get the expected output.

I have two variables `${ASSIMP_INCLUDE_DIR}` and `${ASSIMP_LIBRARY}`.

In a `release` build:

```
${ASSIMP_INCLUDE_DIR} = C:/lib/assimp/3.0/include
${ASSIMP_LIBRARY} = C:/lib/assimp/3.0/lib/assimp_release-dll_win32/assimp.lib
```

My main `CMake` file which brings everything together goes something like this (with a lot of unrelated stuff stripped out):

```
set(EXE "main")

# Add sub-directories to create libraries from my files
add_subdirectory(various_sub_dirs)

add_executable(${EXE} my_sources.cpp)

# Link up my sub-directory libraries
target_link_libraries(${EXE} various_libraries_from_my_code)

# Link up external libraries
target_link_libraries(${EXE} ${ASSIMP_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(${EXE} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${EXE} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(${EXE} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
# etc...
```

I don't get any `include` errors, so I know the `inlcude directory` is being used correctly, but for some reason, even though I can print out the exact path to the `.lib` file I am linking, it either isn't actually linking, or I'm linking the wrong thing.

Does anybody know why I am seeing these linker errors?

Do I need to link a different file? Or perhaps I need to link it in a certain order?

Any help would be appreciated because I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

If any more information is needed, please leave a comment and I will edit the question as soon as I can.

Comment: How are you building this?  Have you checked that C:/lib/assimp/3.0/lib/assimp_release-dll_win32/assimp.lib is listed in the link command?

Comment: @Fraser I am building with MinGW on Windows 7 via make files which are generated with CMake.
I just turned on VERBOSE=1 for the make command and I can see that the path to the .lib file is being included at the linking stage with g++.
The output I can see is basically this (... is where I have omitted things): "C:\mingw_path\g++.exe -std=c++11 -Wall ... -o C:\bin_path\main.exe ... C:\lib\assimp\3.0\lib\assimp_release-dll_win32\assimp.lib ...". I have tried using the assimp.lib, Assimp32.dll and Assimp64.dll files, but all of them give the same result (actually the x64 dll is not recognised).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with MinGW I'm afraid.  My only suggestion would be to try linking assimp last in case one of the other libs has it as a dependency.  Just try moving the `target_link_libraries(${EXE} ${ASSIMP_LIBRARY})` to the end of all the `target_link_libraries` calls.

Comment: @Fraser Thank you for you're time, but it seems the problem was with the pre-compiled files that came with the download. I just compiled the library files myself with CMake and Make, and used those files instead and now it is working without any problems at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the pre-compiled libraries that came with the full download of Assimp 3.0.

I used CMake and Make to compile the Assimp libraries myself and now it is working without any problems.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you got this to work? When I try to compile using CMake and VS2013, I get an .exe that has unresolved methods (checked using Dependency Walker).